# Define an interface for object as const

Tags: typescript

How can one define an interface for an object that defined `as const`.

`Events` type won't work and break the enforcement.

```
const events = { // how do i define an interface for events?
    test: payload => console.log(payload),
    another: payload => console.log(payload)
} as const;

type Events = { [key: string]: (payload: Payload) => void }; // this won't work for events object
type Payload = { [key: string]: any };
type EventName = keyof typeof events;

const emit = (event: EventName, payload: Payload) => {
    events[event]?.(payload); 
} // (parameter) event: "test" | "another"

emit('foo', { test: 1 }); // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"test" | "another"'.
```

[See TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KFIodYu4NosQA)

Comment: Can you not do `typeof events`? What would an explicit interface definition look like?

Comment: see the `Events` type, however you want the key to come from `events` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract an interface from the shape of the `events` object and enforce the right parameters type for the function `emit`:

```
// Create the object of events.
// Specify the type of the payload if not `any`.
const events = {
    test: (payload: any) => console.log(payload),
    another: (payload: {test:number}) => console.log(payload),
} as const;

// Extract event names from the keys of the object.
type EventName = keyof typeof events;

// Extract the payload type associated to each event.
// `Parameters` extract the parameters of a function and returns them in an array.
// Ex: Parameters<(a: string, b: number) => void> returns [string, number].
type Payload = { [key in EventName]: Parameters<typeof events[key]>[0] };

// Type the function `emit`.
const emit = <T extends EventName>(event: T, payload: Payload[T]) => {
    events[event]?.(payload); 
}

emit('test', {anything: 'can be passed'}); // `test` takes any payload.
emit('another', {test: 2}); // `another` takes an object with a property `test`.
emit('another', {}); // Omitting the property generates an error.
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGECcFMEMBdqngCyQewEYCtoGN5R0AzUaAN2gDt4BnAOgCg90rbCLq7QBeUAb0ahhyaOwBcoABQAHWAE8ANulgATSbCryAlLwB8oFm3SLo9ZQHNZC5Wu0AaISM3pU0SJOtKV6gYglUAK4AtpjuAL66PAZGtCZmll62qg6M4aCwtIas7ADcjIwgoACiAB7wkLAEZJQ0oFSwwWKgxJDowchooADW0PJZJJ0YOPjwTPDyMkjFtfAAco1IfL3ygxNTg5w0tPmFYGUVVYRuoHLeasiTSJlxeACWCNCqyOhkVSg1XExFAAYACrBKk1EJBaD8yOVKtUTnIgdAQQNSLAWoEqAQ7qwMlRnjB4IFIGwhh07lQsRlIJV5N99qVJAC4QiADxSWCSdiQEkWeygTCSIKhdxRAzkdB3VQGXH4wkAbXZnO5-LCkAAuuMrqAAednnx%20KBpStQCSSrMFk1lXTAYsmetoJtZrR9X1lXppQAGZWgcK7IoAFXVJ2IqPRmJ%200GCd3gPyYsQ44cIfEZPohiGxWRmXFN0D0Ui28EkPu5Z2SFq10p9yqFAicwlzDtzyoA-PQkj5tLlQGkCmGI1IAOT%20eC97n8TTyVCcyS9vCaHlIOS0WhPXuRdu-Afg%20CwXpZUenGw%20Jjd%20B9lxuSBDvxiPOgABMK9Av1PaEgG63zRnWFw1QA7hGPsiZDaKZIAmUAfnXQ84xPKhXGfC9%20HvIoAHk43gTkhlOID3FAixqHcR4d1Jdw2kgeggA)

If you want to support another event, just add it in the object `events`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! it is kind of how it works currently as if you type the payload. however I want to enforce the same shape for all events object, so any key has a function with a payload typed as Payload and returns void.