# How to build type definition from array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I have some data I create manually:

```
const fields = [{ id: 'myId', value: '', type: 'text' }, { id: 'myId2', value: '', type: 'select' }]
```

OR

```
const fields = { myId: { value: '', type: 'text' }, myId2: { value: '', type: 'select' } }
```

I would like to build an interface like:

```
type Out = { myId: string; myId2: CustomType }
```

`string` or `CustomType` will depends on what I pass to `type` field.

Entire example will be used to build type for values in `onSubmit` handler which will define available fields (by id from fields data) and depends what it defined in `type` field in input data (union type).

Comment: Just add `as const` at the end of the array literal, then use `type Out = typeof fields[number];` to get `Out`. This is covered by many previous questions and their answers, I'll try to find a couple to point to. For instance, [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75820967/extract-props-from-objects-in-array-as-union-without-making-the-array-readonly), but it has an additional constraint you don't seem to have.

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497388/typescript-array-to-string-literal-type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281294/define-an-interface-for-object-as-const

Comment: it will not work since it gives me `{id: "myId", type: "text", value: ""} | {id: "myId2", type: "select", value: ""}` as `Out` type

Comment: That just requires tweaking with a mapped type. What are you expecting `CustomType` to be? And which of your examples are you trying to do this for? Right now you're asking two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first need a map of type names (strings) to TypeScript types:

```
interface TypeMap {
    text: string;
    select: CustomType;
}
```

Then, you can define a type that can take an array of fields and create a type from them, using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type TypeFromArray<A extends readonly { id: string; value: string; type: keyof TypeMap }[]> = {
    [K in A[number] as K["id"]]: TypeMap[K["type"]];
};

const fields = [
    { id: "myId", value: "", type: "text" },
    { id: "myId2", value: "", type: "select" },
] as const; // note the 'as const'

type X = TypeFromArray<typeof fields>;
//   ^? { myId: string; myId2: CustomType }
```

Similarly, you can also create a type to transform an object:

```
type TypeFromObject<O extends Readonly<Record<string, { value: string; type: keyof TypeMap }>>> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof O]: TypeMap[O[K]["type"]];
};

const fields = {
    myId: { value: "", type: "text" },
    myId2: { value: "", type: "select" },
} as const; // note the 'as const'

type X = TypeFromObject<typeof fields>;
//   ^? { myId: string; myId2: CustomType }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFcFtoTwgUwGYEsB2qAuqD26AoLOAB0VAGFIBnLXaAFVPIF5QBvUZXXALlABGPADaIAhulABfANwECGLIgBOyMQGNyTMgFkxJDgVDHQSgB5Z+tZRgDmck6GqJR6y5Rp1GzOVPnEyUG1EADFlegBBZWUxOAAeCNBEC0R0cGpQZXFwfGEETlRwKywbdHtQADcxYUhEYtLygLrQAGtEOFxkIOY9AykAbQBdAD5QNnYjE36AaVAMUAj+9BgBFUHQMQzp-oAiQp3Bwf5g3pndpoPB3zkiZm6yMPoAeQEAK0Q3OKeklLSMgCVsrl4oD1LhlOA4tY7AAaDiVaq1ep2GSmZj8NodLonfTSYb4saGRwAWiyYhy6DyoBmc0kmM6oCeR3uiFOTxmg3OzEu13kE0cYPQtC4qBc6UJ-UmjmMBSKoB28AAkuAdnCqjVmjtVWiyPwduYsDtpDCpdLZXqleAAEza9VI+Xapp65yuQ3G03rTagQW0G6OJqgAAahOCj2gURi8SaDLQYuowwcJhAJgAegB+Ah+Aj8kw+rAiuOEnPS0CW-icO2ax3o+UGo1SE0l4yWq3lhEavXV3Xyl0fN0N01SDYZPN+kwB4NsUPhaAvd6faNdWPCdIJ03J4zpzMEIA)